# Outlook Mail add-in / Plugin

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, add-in

I have my Outlook mail add-in ready working on my local machine and its working as expected.
But when migrated to the live server I am facing some issues. What I am getting errors is the error for fetching the resources.
Please note that plugin does gets installed but it doesn't start due to this error.

Any help would be appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could redeploy your add-in/plugin.

Add-in deployment, You could refer to the following link:

[Deploy and publish your Office Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish?context=outlook/context)

[Host an Office Add-in on Microsoft Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/host-an-office-add-in-on-microsoft-azure?context=outlook/context)

[Package your add-in using Visual Studio to prepare for publishing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/package-your-add-in-using-visual-studio?context=outlook/context)

[Make your solutions available in AppSource and within Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/submit-to-the-office-store?context=outlook/context)

Hope that helps!